# Is it OK to create very large tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, collections, tuples

I have a quite large list (>1K elements) of objects of the same type in my Python program. The list is never modified - no elements are added, removed or changed. Are there any downside to putting the objects into a tuple instead of a list?

On the one hand, tuples are immutable so that matches my requirements. On the other hand, using such a large tuple just *feels* wrong. In my mind, tuples has always been for small collections. It's a double, a tripple, a quadruple... Not a two-thousand-and-fiftyseven-duple.

Is my fear of large tuples somehow justified? Is it bad for performance, unpythonic, or otherwise bad practice?

Comment: @Jan Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can not do `len(generator)`. And I need to be able to do that.

Comment: Tuples for heterogenous structures, lists for homogenous structures.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, the manual says that how they are generally used. But it doesn't say bad things will happend if you use tuples for heterogenous data. Will something bad happend? If so, what?

Comment: @Jan I want to be able to do it after creation time. And the data needs to be stored in memory anyway.

Comment: How are you creating the list in the first place? Since you can't build up a tuple piece by piece, I can only imagine you want to do something like `my_tuple = tuple(my_list)`, but in that case, what is the *benefit*  to doing so? The time it takes to create the tuple from a pre-exisiting list doesn't seem worth it just to ensure nobody tries to modify it.

Comment: @chepner The tuple is created from a generator (that is reading from a file). So I will either feed the generator to `list()` or `tuple()`.

Comment: This is a great use of tuples and if you don't want modification, its preferred. I have no idea what the whole heterogeneous / homogeneous thing is, it sounds totally bizarre to me.

Comment: Internally, both are just contiguous memory regions, so there should not be any difference in performance. A tuple might occupy less space as lists would have some extra space preallocated, but that should never matter in practice. The only difference you should care about is whether you want to protect the object from editing or not.

Comment: As long as your access to the items is either direct (subscript) or sequential, tuple is exactly correct.  If you need associative access (find something by its value), then you'll likely want a set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In CPython, go ahead.  Under the covers, the only real difference between the storage of lists and tuples is that the C-level array holding the tuple elements is allocated *in* the tuple object, while a list object contains a pointer *to* a C-level array holding the list elements, which is allocated separately from the list object.  The list implementation needs to do that because the list may grow, and so the memory containing the C-level vector may need to change its base address.  A tuple can't change size, so the memory for it is allocated directly in the tuple object.

I've created tuples with millions of elements, and yet I lived to type about it ;-)

### Obscure

In CPython, there can even be "a reason" to prefer giant tuples:  the cyclic garbage collection scheme exempts a tuple from periodic scanning if it only contains immutable objects.  Then the tuple can never be part of a cycle, so cyclic gc can ignore it.  The same optimization cannot be used for lists; just because a list contains only immutable objects during one run of cyclic gc says nothing about whether that will still be the case during the next run.

This is almost never highly significant, but it can save a percent or so in a long-running program, and the benefit of exempting giant tuples grows the bigger they are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is OK.

However, depending on the operations you're doing, you might want to consider using the `set` function in Python. This will convert your input iterable (tuple, list, or other) to a set. Sets are nice for a few reasons, but especially because you get a unique list of items that has constant time lookup for items.

There's nothing "un-pythonic" about holding large data sets in memory, though.